# How to properly align columns with Flexbox on Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

We have a set of columns defined by using widths and [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). The reason behind using fixed widths is to get around the IE Bug regarding the [flex-basis and how IE 10-11 ignore calc()](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-8). Since we are using Flexbox, we do not want to use the `float: left` property that other frameworks like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/css/) may use.

All works well on all browsers except Safari 9, 10.1, and 11.

How can we fix the alignment so that we get everything lines up in two rows of four columns for Safari?

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1440px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container:before, .container:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
 }

.container:after {
  clear: both;
}

.flex__row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.flex__row--wrap{
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex__col {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .col--m-s-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col--t-s-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .col--t-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

[class*=col--] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex__row flex__row--wrap">
    <div class="col--m-s-12 col--t-s-6 col--t-3 flex__col ns-flex__col--padding-sml">
      <i class="fa fa-cube fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col--m-s-12 col--t-s-6 col--t-3 flex__col ns-flex__col--padding-sml">
      <i class="fa fa-lock fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col--m-s-12 col--t-s-6 col--t-3 flex__col ns-flex__col--padding-sml">
      <i class="fa fa-bath fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col--m-s-12 col--t-s-6 col--t-3 flex__col ns-flex__col--padding-sml">
      <i class="fa fa-adjust fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col--m-s-12 col--t-s-6 col--t-3 flex__col ns-flex__col--padding-sml">
      <i class="fa fa-bars fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col--m-s-12 col--t-s-6 col--t-3 flex__col ns-flex__col--padding-sml">
      <i class="fa fa-arrows fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col--m-s-12 col--t-s-6 col--t-3 flex__col ns-flex__col--padding-sml">
      <i class="fa fa-bus fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col--m-s-12 col--t-s-6 col--t-3 flex__col ns-flex__col--padding-sml">
      <i class="fa fa-archive fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Current Result on breakpoint > 1024px
[image: current safari issue]

Desired Result on breakpoint > 1024px:
[image: chrome/firefox/IE/Edge]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue with Safari 10.1.

Comment: @HunterTurner were you able to reproduce on Safari 11 or 9?

Comment: I didn't test it in those. The version I had on my computer was 10.1.

Comment: @HunterTurner i know why it didn't work. I will update the question to reflect the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I removed the following css below I was able to resolve the issue.

```
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
 }

.container:after {
  clear: both;
}
```